# hard drive fell over

Tags: data-recovery

My Ubuntu 16.04 failed in mid session and failed to reboot with self checking/analysis suggesting hard drive failure (now I'm not so sure this was the case).

I replaced the hard drive and then used testdisk with some success to recover files, however I would like to know if given the message below when I connected old drive using external method can I "patch the old hard drive" to simply recover the files. The message I get when truing to access is as below. I'm not computer literate when it comes to actual Ubuntu syntax and commands. I like the Ubuntu operating system and have managed mainly through trying this or trying that to get things working.

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb2: Command-line   
`mount "/mnt/usb-TO_Exter_nal_USB_3.0_201503310007F-0:0-part2"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:   
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,   
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. What were you doing prior to the failure? Did it happen just like this, did the hardware get hit?

Comment: ok  running ubuntu 16.04 on a inspiron 17r laptop, was writing an email using outlook... the laptop froze when I pushed send for the email...totally froze up including no mouse  either through touch pad or mouse...however still had outlook screen showing...I held power down and turned off  laptop and then attempted restart... which failed... tried to restart through the ubuntu menu at start but no luck ... ran inspiron diagnosis which said error on hard drive

Comment: replaced the hard drive with new unit and installed 16.04 .....then tried to recover data from old hard drive using an external hard drive reader connected by USB and using program testdisk ...

Comment: trying then to see if we have genuine fault with old hard drive or just simply some corrupted files preventing access.... I took the old hard drive apart to ensure the moving pieces were all still as they should be...and you can hear the disk powering up as normally expected

Comment: the problem is I am not literate enough with ubuntu and terminal commands to get only the files I want back or generating part files ( mp3 is good example I retrieved mp3 but many were shortened to just over a minute and numerous copies)

Comment: And mounting the external drive does not work as stated in the question, I assume. Did you run `fsck /dev/<device_id>` with the matching partitions of your old hard drive, yet? Your mount command also complains about the wrong FS-type. Try getting the FS type from `lsblk -f` and mounting with `mount -t <type>`.

Comment: Usually, it is not possible to fix a failed HDD, and recovering files after the fact can be quite expensve. A much better strategy would be to keep regular backups of all important files.